# Arrow chat unable to chat with members in wordrpess multinetwork when guest can chat option is disabled

Tags: wordpress

I have installed and integrated arrowchat with WordPress multinetwork v4.9 on localhost . I can chat as guest when Chat as Guest is checked. But when it's unchecked logged in users cannot chat.

Now there are two scenarios

WordPress Multinetwork:
1. we can Chat when Guest option is checked. But when it's unchecked logged in users cannot chat. 
2. when Guest can chat with admin only option is enabled, then it shows 0 login users for chat (while users are login)

Single WordPress:
1. When Gest chat option is disabled, and users can chat with members, it works fine. 
2. when users chat with admin only option is enable then it shows 0 members to chat (while users are login)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, to fix this issue in wordpress multinetwork you have to make some little changes in the code.

1. login to wordpress network and open cookeis (F12 or developer tools)
2. you will see cookies "wordpress_sec_5455e9329ad280ebcc9b2f7841bb7af1" copy the cookie value 5455e9329ad280ebcc9b2f7841bb7af1.
3. Now open the arrowchat/includes/integration.php and find "$cookiehash5 = md5("http://www." . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/");"
4. Now change this to $cookiehash5 = "5455e9329ad280ebcc9b2f7841bb7af1";

Now logout and login agian, it will work.

Cheers :)